# Returning a Boolean Value via PDO Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting with no success to return a Boolean Value from the following PHP/PDO call back to jQuery/AJAX:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)" .
    "FROM bu_users" .
    "WHERE user_email = :email";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_GET[reg_email]));

if(!$stmt){
    $result = $stmt->errorInfo();
} else {
    $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
}

print_r($result);
```

I am outputting my results via console.log but am only receiving empty responses whether the email matches a database row or not. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Even if the count is zero, the query didn't fail so the statement will return true. You need to fetch the column and check the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL syntax problems:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)" .
    "FROM bu_users" .
     ^---
    "WHERE user_email = :email";
     ^---
```

You're lacking spaces at the indicated spots, and your query ends up looking like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)FROM bu_usersWHERE user_email = :email;
              ^^--         ^^--
```

Don't generate multiline strings like that. It's far too easy to make silly mistakes like this. At least use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc):

```
$sql = <<<EOL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM bu_users
WHERE user_email = :email
EOL;
```

No need for concatentation, automatic multi-line usage, and you can nicely format your SQL as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM bu_users WHERE user_email = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['reg_email']));
echo json_encode((bool)$stmt->fetchColumn());
```

Comment: Thank you. After correcting the error Marc pointed out, I used your json_encode((bool)... to convert.